# Toast Not Working Properly

Tags: android, toast

I've created an application in Android Studio; it's working fine but the Toast is not showing properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="click"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

NextActivity.java

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    final EditText fName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    final EditText lName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hi there!, "+fName+ " " + " "+ lName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

activity.next.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:hint="Enter your first name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:hint="Enter your last name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp" />
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "the Toast is not showing properly" means.

Comment: When I enter a first name and a last name in the second activity and press the submit button, what is shown for the toast is the text "Hi there!" and the rest is a bunch of signs and letters. The parts for "fName" and "lName" are not shown.

Comment: fName and iName are EditText objects. If you want to get the string you should do `fName.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget TextView.getText()

NextActivity.java

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    final EditText fName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    final EditText lName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hi there!, "+fName.getText().toString()+ " " + " "+ lName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }); 

} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to add the text content of your `EditText`s - the sequence of letters and numbers you see are a result of the default `Object` [`toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html):

> `public String toString ()`
>
> Added in API level 1 Returns a string containing a concise,
>   human-readable description of this object. Subclasses are encouraged
>   to override this method and provide an implementation that takes into
>   account the object's type and data. The default implementation is
>   equivalent to the following expression:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

If you want to grab the content of your `EditText` widgets, you would instead `editText.getText().toString()`